# For loop how to print to console without leaving on first iteration java

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

I have written a `for` loop which counts each value in an array and if that array does NOT contain a given number (`numberIn`) that the user has entered, then a relavent error will appear.

However I noticed that I get a dead code warning on `i++` as it only iterates once. Is there a way for the loop to iterate fully?

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (!(numberIn == array[i]))
        System.out.println("WRONG!!!!!");
        break;
}
```

EDIT: sorry everyone for the massive confusion!, what i meant to say was that i want an error to appear if the value is NOT in the array, sorry again! :(

Comment: _"if that array contains the number (numberIn) the user has entered then a relavent error will appear"_ In that case, why are you using `!(numberIn == array[i])`? Once the brace problem is fixed, the only way that the loop will complete successfully is if `numberIn` is equal to _all_ of the elements in the array.

Comment: I see, I thought that it would compare each value and only print the message once a value is found, how would i change it? thank you btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you are trying to test for the case when `numberIn` is *not in* the array. In that case, the simplest approach is to loop through the array, keeping track of whether the value was found, and then check whether it was found after that:

```
boolean found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (numberIn == array[i]) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}  

if (!found) {
    System.out.println("WRONG!!!!!");
}
```

You can also do this a bit more cleanly if you use a method:

```
boolean contains(array, value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (value == array[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }  
    return false;
}


if (!contains(array, numberIn)) {
    System.out.println("WRONG!!!!!");
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! I didn't think i would have had to use much more than the basic if and for statements, but obviously i needed a boolean, makes perfect sense. Also to everyone else massive sorry over the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

you need curly brackets {} around the if statement, otherwise it will always exit after one iteration. Without {} an if statement only applies to the statement immediately below it. In this case the `System.out.println("WRONG!!!!!");` statement. the `break` statement is not part of the if statement by default. The curly brackets indicate that everything inside of them is only to be executed in the event the condition is true, rather than just the next single statement.

EDIT: also, you had it writing the output in the event that it didn't detect a match. It should println() ony in the event that there is a match. remove the ! from the if statement, and it should work.

Fixed version

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (numberIn == array[i]){
             System.out.println("WRONG!!!!!");
             break;
         }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I have tried this but I am getting another error, no matter if the input is found in the array a message is always written, I want it to write that statement if that input is in the array only, thank you again btw

Comment: @aluckii there was also an error in that you had the of the negation of the correct condition. see my edits.

Comment: Thanks again, I have again implemented this and It does indeed work if the value is in the array, however I wanted it to do it if it was not in the array, sorry about the confusion!, I have tried all answers here and unfortunatly I cannot come to a solution

Answer (score 0):

You break from your loop regardless whether or not the if statement evaluates to true.

Fix:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (!(numberIn == array[i])){
        System.out.println("WRONG!!!!!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, just tried this however I now get that message even if that number is in the array, I only want the message if it isn't thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `break` in your `if` block. Right now, it's always executing.

See:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (!(numberIn == array[i])) {
    System.out.println("WRONG!!!!!");
    break;
  }
}
```

In general, the use of `break` is considered bad practice. Perhaps consider converting this to a `while` loop if you would like to stop after the first error is detected.

Comment: Thank you I will try that, hopefully i will find a solution

Answer (score 0):

When you call for a break, it will leave the loop you are currently in.
Simply take out the `break;`  allowing it to run through all values.

EDIT: Put the break inside the brackets. I don't think he wants it to run forever, just until he finds the value.

Comment: I think the intention is to break out of the loop once the condition has been met.

Comment: thanks, Just tried this, I am just getting the messgae printed to the console the same amount of times of the length of the array

Answer (score 0):

You need more braces eg:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (!(numberIn == array[i])){
                 System.out.println("WRONG!!!!!");
                 break;

 }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is forgetting to put brackets in your "if" statement. Your code looks like this:

```
 if (!(numberIn == array[i]))
                   System.out.println("WRONG!!!!!");
   break;
```

Therefore no matter if the if statement is run, the break will be run.

Put the break inside the if statement and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your break hits because it's not in the if statement, you should put the break inside the if statement it will work

```html
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (!(numberIn == array[i]))
               {
                 System.out.println("WRONG!!!!!");
                 break;
               }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is a problem with your braces:

Without the if-statement body having braces, it's actually parsed as the following, which probably isn't what you intended:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (!(numberIn == array[i])) {
        System.out.println("WRONG!");
    }
    break;
}
```

Hopefully this makes it clearer to see why your loop will always break after one iteration. Adding the braces, and putting the break back where you want it should resolve your issue (I've also slightly re-written your `if` condition):

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (numberIn != array[i]) {
        System.out.println("CORRECT!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int array[] = {1,2,3};
        int numberIn = 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (!(numberIn == array[i])){
                 System.out.println("WRONG!!!!!");
                 break;
            }
        } 
    }
```

You need the brackets on if sentence :D

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other posts that the break should be withing brackets in the if statement, but according to what you are saying that you the loop is supposed to do, the logic does not appear correct either.  You have said that you only want the error message to appear if the value is found in the loop so if I am understanding correctly what the loop intends to do, it should read:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if ( numberIn == array[i] ) 
        {
             System.out.println("WRONG!!!!!");
             break;
        }
}
```